# Looking for a really odd dinosaur show?

Tags: story-identification, dinosaurs

So there was 3 characters I think. One was an adult white dude who I think sort of looked like Megaman? I'm pretty sure he had blue armor and maybe a helmet. The other character was a girl who I think had pink armor. And the last character was a triceratops kid who could talk and walk on two legs. They went around in some sort of space ship.

The only thing I remember happening in the show was them going to rescue dinosaurs before they went extinct but they could only save two baby stegosauruses I think. Also, a scene from the intro where they flew their ship through the mouth of a T-Rex before it could eat them.

---

We've ruled out:

<s>Dino-riders

Dino-Saucers

Extreme Dinosaurs!

Diplodo</s>

Comment: Do you remember when you watched it? Whether it was a cartoon or not, what channels it may have appeared on?

Comment: I remember I got the dvd of it from a 99 cent store. I don't know what age I watched it on but I was pretty young and I was born in 2001. The 99 cent store can have some pretty old dvds so it may have been from the 90s. It was an animated show that had a somewhat anime style to it as well. Not dino-riders.

Comment: or dino-saucers

Comment: none of those either :(

Comment: I wonder if this could be Cadillacs and Dinosaurs? it was made in the early 1990's i believe. Here is the wikipedia entry. See if it rings any bells.

Comment: Here is the  link to the opening sequence on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr2iQ96em2w

Comment: Note to self stop pressing enter instead of space between sentences! Main character wears blue although its not armour, female character wears red not pink. Opening prominently features a T rex or allosaur snapping at the characters. Not exactly what you describe but perhaps close?